# panel.2dsmoother in latticeExtra: biased interpolation in upper line of the graph

Tags: r, interpolation, levelplot

I am having an issue with the panel.2dsmoother inside the levelplot-function. It seems that, compared to the original data, the upper row has higher values in the smoothed plot. Is this a general problem of panel.2dsmoother? When I invert the y-axis, the bias is at the bottom of the plot.
Thank you in advance!

```
colredblue<-colorRampPalette(c("red2","white","royalblue2"))
colblue<-colorRampPalette(c("white","royalblue2"))

levelplot(SPEI_05 ~ year*month, data=obl_spei, col.regions=colredblue(100), main="SPEI_05_original", at=seq(from=-4,to=4,by=0.5))
levelplot(SPEI_05 ~ year*month, data=obl_spei, col.regions=colredblue(100), main="SPEI_05_smoothed", at=seq(from=-4,to=4,by=0.5), panel=panel.2dsmoother,args=list(span=0.01),n = 500)

levelplot(cld ~ year*month, data=obl_cru, col.regions=colblue(100), main="cld_original", at=seq(from=0,to=160,by=2))
levelplot(cld ~ year*month, data=obl_cru, col.regions=colblue(100), main="cld_smoothed", at=seq(from=0,to=160,by=2), panel=panel.2dsmoother,args=list(span=0.01),n = 500)
```

[image: comparison latticeExtra levelplots panel.2dsmoother]